# Emacs style highlighting for incremental search in vim

Tags: vim, highlight

In Vim, is there a way to enable on-the-fly highlighting for *all* matches when searching?

If I enable incsearch and type "/something" it will highlight the first match only. If I enable hlsearch and type "/something", nothing happens until I press enter (it only highlights the previous search).

In emacs the first match will be highlighted, and (after a slight delay) all other matches on the screen are highlighted in a different color, giving almost instant feedback when scanning for matches in a piece of code.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't answer your question, but maybe [this Wikia post](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip572) can help?

Quote from that post:

> Put the following code in your vimrc, or create file
>   ~/.vim/plugin/autohighlight.vim (Unix) or
>   $HOME/vimfiles/plugin/autohighlight.vim (Windows) containing the
>   script below. Then restart Vim.
>
> To automatically highlight the current word, type `z/`. To turn off,
>   type `z/` again.
>
> ```
> " Highlight all instances of word under cursor, when idle.
> " Useful when studying strange source code.
> " Type z/ to toggle highlighting on/off.
> nnoremap z/ :if AutoHighlightToggle()<Bar>set hls<Bar>endif<CR>
> function! AutoHighlightToggle()
>   let @/ = ''
>   if exists('#auto_highlight')
>     au! auto_highlight
>     augroup! auto_highlight
>     setl updatetime=4000
>     echo 'Highlight current word: off'
>     return 0
>   else
>     augroup auto_highlight
>       au!
>       au CursorHold * let @/ = '\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'
>     augroup end
>     setl updatetime=500
>     echo 'Highlight current word: ON'
>     return 1
>   endif
> endfunction
> ```

Comment: Interesting, though I don't immediately see how this could be used to implement what I'm looking for... (especially if one wants two colors)

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your .vimrc

```
hi Search guifg=black guibg=#C6C5FE gui=BOLD ctermfg=black ctermbg=cyan cterm=BOLD
```

Of course, you might want to change the colors to suit your needs.

Comment: Read the question again and decide if your answer has got to do anything with it.