# Vim: highlight all matches in incsearch

Tags: vim

I'm using the `incsearch` and `hlsearch` options. All matches are highlighted after I press enter, but only the first one as I type. I'd like to highlight all matches as I type.

How can I get that behavior?

Comment: I was messing around in Sublime Text today (I was a happy ST user till I re-discovered Vim) and this is something I want to see in Vim eventually

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs style highlighting for incremental search in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791584/emacs-style-highlighting-for-incremental-search-in-vim). Answers should be merged

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [incsearch.vim plugin](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim):

[image: Automatic :nohlsearch]

*[Install](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim#installation) with your favourite plugin manager and [map your search key(s) to call the plugin's search](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim#basic-usage).*

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible without writing your own search in Vimscript (capturing each key via `getchar()`, highlighting via `:match`), or patching the core Vim source code in C.

The reason this isn't implemented is probably to keep the incsearch snappy and immediate.

**Update**: Highlighting all matches now is the default behavior starting with Vim 7.4.2259 (*with 'incsearch' can only see the next match*).

Comment: I bet somebody could figure out a way to do this asynchronously and use only free cycles to fill in the rest of the matches (and only the ones visible in the buffer, anyhow). Do you know if Vim's architecture would lend well to that kind of thing, or would the computation have to block after being triggered by each key?

Comment: @StevenLu Vim is inherently single-threaded, so this could be difficult.

Comment: @StevenLu This is the default behavior in Emacs, so I would assume it's not that hard to achieve in Vim too.

Comment: @Xdxter Could you elaborate on the reasoning behind that assumption? Emacs has nothing to do with Vim other than the fact that it's been around for a while too.

Comment: @Xdxter see [incsearch.vim](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim) (in my answer).

Comment: The point about speed is to highlight only what's visible on the screen. For highlighting there's no need to search through the full file while the user is still typing the search pattern. I guess, that's why there are plugins available already. Would be nice if this Q&A changes the accepted answer as it is being linked to by duplicates..

Comment: @cfi Don't forget remote editing over slow connections. Granted, this is rare today (but fully in line with Vim's decades-old heritage), but with only a few bits per second, it matters whether only a single line or almost the entire screen is redrawn on each key stroke.

Comment: Granted, but that is not the reason for not _implementing_ it. It may be a reason for not switching it on. That aside: You're still seeing this anywhere? I'm old enough to be a first hand witness, but nowadays I'm playing networked games on my phone even outside of UMTS reach, I'm controlling guis via compressing vnc session across the atlantic ocean, and we've got remote sessions on 8 bit embedded cpus in the labs. Nothing is that slow anymore. Of course, there's probably still the odd corner case out there. Rare indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong about this because the answer seems deceptively simple, but just enable `incsearch` and `hlsearch` at the same time with:

```
set incsearch
set hlsearch
```